# Mocking private field in servlet filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, mockito

Is is possible to mock (currently using Mockito, may be also other testing lib) the field 'sf' in the class shown below:

```
public class SomeFilter implements Filter {

   private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
   private SomeField sf = new SomeField();

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
      log.info("");
   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain fc) throws     IOException, ServletException {
        fc.doFilter(request, response);
   }

   @Override
   public void destroy() {
      log.info("");
   }
}
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to make the field either `protected` or `package-private` and then inject the mock in your test, e.g.:

```
final SomeField sf = mock(SomeField.class);
someFilter.sf = sf;
```

Otherwise you could provide a constructor to inject the mock:

```
...
public SomeFilter() {
   this(new SomeField());
}


public SomeFilter(SomeField sf) {
    this.sf = sf;
}
...
```

Then in your test you could pass the mock in like so:

```
final SomeField sf = mock(SomeField.class);
SomeFilter someFilter = new SomeFilter(sf);
```

Comment: Its really not a good idea to design your classes so that they will work with your unit tests!

Comment: @cowls I don't see it as that. I guess what I'm trying to get at is that dependencies should be provided to the class under test. This would make the testing easier and should help the architecture of the system.

Comment: Agreed. But you can use reflection to inject a dependency into a private field. So no need to change the class under test to work with your test

Comment: @cowls That's true and I'm not disagreeing with you. It's just not the approach I would take. :-)

Comment: Actually, good unit tests and good classes go hand in hand and designing your code to unit testing is a great approach. Currently, there is a very high coupling between SomeFilter and SomeField. It would be better if this was be an injectable interface.

Comment: While you can use reflection to make the test work, the fact that you can inject the dependency leads to a better design. You loosen the coupling between SomeFilter and SomeField. Ideally SomeField is an interface and SomeFilter gets it, or a Factory for it, injected in its constructor.

Comment: At the time the project was developed there was no DI used. To be honest I also do not see anything wrong in marking fields protected or without any modifier just to make it better testable. In that simple case reflection seems to be an overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) framework with some nifty features, including [some integration with Mockito framework](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13)

Consider [this example](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation) to bypass encapsulation and access private field, like below

```
String sf = Whitebox.getInternalState(o, "sf", String.class, B.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(o, "sf", "XXX", B.class);
```

Also consider (from the last link):

> *All of these things can be achieved without using PowerMock, this is just normal Java reflection. However reflection requires much boiler-plate code and can be error prone and thus PowerMock provides you with these utility methods instead. PowerMock gives you a choice on whether to refactor your code and add getter/setter methods for checking/altering internal state or whether to use its utility methods to accomplish the same thing without changing the production code. It's up to you!*

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In your Test class you can use `ReflectionTestUtils` from Spring Framework

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html

call the `setField` method like this:

```
SomeFilter filter = new SomeFilter();
SomeField field = Mockito.mock(SomeField.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(filter , "sf", field);
```

You can Mock the object in the test case as you would normally.

If you cannot import Spring Framework it is not too difficult to use Java reflection directly to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and the response, but the project isn't Spring based and I don't want to add depedency for this project for tetsing only.

Comment: If you are using Maven you could add the dependency as test scope so it is only used in the test phase. That way no overhead is added to the actual project. Alternatively, you may have to write your own using Java reflection

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerMock to mock the constructor of the SomeField class. From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor):

### Mock construction of new objects

1. Use the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation at the
   class-level of the test case. Use the
   `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatCreatesTheNewInstance.class)` annotation at
   the class-level of the test case.
2. Use `PowerMock.createMock(NewInstanceClass.class)` to create a mock
   object of the class that should be constructed (let's call it
   mockObject).
3. Use
   `PowerMock.expectNew(NewInstanceClass.class).andReturn(mockObject)` to
   expect a new construction of an object of type
   NewInstanceClass.class but instead return the mock object.
4. Use `PowerMock.replay(mockObject, NewInstanceClass.class)` to change
   the mock object and class to replay mode, alternatively use the
   `PowerMock.replayAll()` method.
5. Use `PowerMock.verify(mockObject, NewInstanceClass.class)` to change
   the mock object and class to verify mode, alternatively use the
   `PowerMock.verifyAll()` method.

If you want to use powermock with [Mockito syntax](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13), then it looks like:

```
whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new IOException("error message"));
```